# Tracking down hacking/malware attempts

Tags: c#, asp.net, malware-detection

I currently have a .net web application on a cluster based system (Rackspace cloud). In web config I have set up the following machine key.

```
<machineKey validationKey='DE0...etc' 
decryptionKey='A97...etc' 
validation='SHA1'/>
```

We were getting a quite a few of the following errors on a daily basis:

> Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If
>   this application is hosted by a Web
>   Farm or cluster, ensure that
>   configuration specifies the same
>   validationKey and validation
>   algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used
>   in a cluster.

I did a bit of Googling and added the following. This has stopped all the previous errors. However it may open the door for various hacking attacks.

```
<pages enableViewStateMac="false">
```

However I am finding now that I get the following errors

> The state information is invalid for
>   this page and might be corrupted.

I am trying to work out what may be causing these two types of errors. Are they bots? Are they genuine web users? Are they hacking/malware attempts? Is this a normal occurrence and I should just ignore them...

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they are Malware/hacking attempts - I have sometimes seen those myself when browsing sites.

The general cause I've seen is that the page hasn't completed loading before the user initiates a postback - there is a hidden field that is rendered at the bottom of the form, and if that hasn't been rendered to the browser when the user clicks a button, the server will reject the viewstate.

There's quite an in-depth post about the issue, and some work-arounds here:

> [Validation of viewstate MAC failed error](http://blogs.msdn.com/tom/archive/2008/03/14/validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error.aspx)

Comment: Cool I had a quick glance, will look in more depth. However it does say as a prerequisite that "You aren't using a web farm" and I am, will this make a difference?

Comment: I believe that's in terms of the repro - I've seen this behaviour on a web farm with configured machine keys if the post back happens before the page has finished loading.